# How to write less code using JavaScript DOM Elements?

Tags: javascript

**Intro**: I am using fetch method to get data from `API`. inside forloop i am not using the template string because somebody told me. it is not a good way to write HTML code inside template sting. So that's why i am using javascript DOM Element to render out the data from `API`. But i am new in JavaScript i want to know how can i write less code with DOM Element. the code below is too much and complicated. I have dropdown menu inside `pending-sale` div which contain a form attributes. Which I haven't written yet, if i write that dropdown menu code my code will be even more complicated as I write the code..

**Needs**: i just want to know how can i write my code less and understandable? Can anyone tell me if the code I am writing is correct? If this is not true, please guide me a little...

I would be grateful for any help.

**main.js**

```
const orderCard = document.querySelector('#pending-sales');

function pendingSaleBuild() {
    orderCard.innerHTML = ''
    fetch('/pending-sale-api/')
        .then((res) => res.json())
        .then((data) => {
            data.map(item => {
                // card title
                const colLg = document.createElement('div')
                colLg.classList.add('col-lg-12')
                const hPanel = document.createElement('div')
                hPanel.classList.add('hpanel')
                hPanel.classList.add('hyellow')
                const pBody = document.createElement('div')
                pBody.classList.add('panel-body')
                hPanel.appendChild(pBody)
                colLg.appendChild(hPanel)
                orderCard.appendChild(colLg)

                const h5 = document.createElement('h5');
                h5.classList.add('text-capitalize')

                // card tilte link
                const a = document.createElement('a');
                h5.appendChild(a)
                linkText = document.createTextNode(item.customers);
                a.appendChild(linkText);
                a.href = "#";
                pBody.appendChild(h5);

                // hr Element
                const hr = document.createElement('hr');
                pBody.appendChild(hr)

                // row div
                const rowDiv = document.createElement('div');
                rowDiv.classList.add('row');

                // project - label div
                const colDiv = document.createElement('div');
                colDiv.classList.add('col-sm-4');
                rowDiv.appendChild(colDiv);

                // project lable div
                const proLable = document.createElement('div');
                proLable.classList.add('project-label');
                proLable.innerText = 'Saler Name';
                colDiv.appendChild(proLable);

                // small text Element
                const smallEle1 = document.createElement('small')
                smallEle1.innerText = item.saler
                colDiv.appendChild(smallEle1);

                const colDiv2 = document.createElement('div');
                colDiv2.classList.add('col-sm-4');
                rowDiv.appendChild(colDiv2);
                // project lable div
                const proLable2 = document.createElement('div');
                proLable2.classList.add('project-label');
                proLable2.innerText = 'Timestamp';
                colDiv2.appendChild(proLable2);

                // small text Element
                const smallEle2 = document.createElement('small')
                smallEle2.innerText = 'item.created_on'
                colDiv2.appendChild(smallEle2);

                const colDiv3 = document.createElement('div');
                colDiv3.classList.add('col-sm-4');
                rowDiv.appendChild(colDiv3);
                // project lable div
                const proLable3 = document.createElement('div');
                proLable3.classList.add('project-label');
                proLable3.innerText = 'Total Price';
                colDiv3.appendChild(proLable3);

                // small text Element
                const smallEle3 = document.createElement('small')
                smallEle3.innerText = '$ 124547'
                colDiv3.appendChild(smallEle3);

                pBody.appendChild(rowDiv);
            })
        });
};
```

Comment: DOM elements are not JavaScript; they're supplied by the browser environment.

Comment: Don't use `.map()` if you're not going to use its return value. The better option would be `.forEach()` or to re-write the method so it only adds the elements once after the loop instead of one element at a time.

Comment: Dear can you write little code with `forEach()` for better understanding

Comment: No, but check the documentation for [`.forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) and you should be able to find the small change that you would have to make.

Comment: That's pretty much how you create HTML dynamically. Thought it's a bit verbose, it's lightning fast. Note, that [`classList.add`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMTokenList/add) takes multiple arguments. To make the code more readable, you could create an utility function, which builds an element based on the passed data, and in the loop you only need to call that function and insert the returned elements to the DOM.

Comment: Are you allowed to use HTML and CSS? The only dynamic value is **linkText = document.createTextNode(item.customers);**, so you could write a template in html and css, then take and copy it with JS on response and populate link value